# Reuse PagingState in another execution in Cassandra

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, cql

Is there possible to store and transform into a String, a base64 or anything that I can return in JSON, to populate the object in another execution.

I found this example, but I'm not getting how to convert and decovert the ByteBuffer.

```
ResultSet rs = session.execute("your query");
ByteBuffer pagingState = rs.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();

// Finish processing the current page
while (rs.getAvailableWithoutFetching() > 0) {
  Row row = rs.one();
  // process the row
}

// Later:
SimpleStatement statement =
    SimpleStatement.builder("your query").setPagingState(pagingState).build();
session.execute(statement);
```

I have clients with milions of registers, which I need to paginate my queries, if there is another way to paginate the Cassandra Query in different executions, I appreciate if somebody can share.